# Why can't I use pytorch to multi-cuda calculate distance? (Initialization Error for default and bad value(s) in fds_in_keep for spawn)

Tags: python, pytorch, python-multiprocessing

I'm using pytorch not for network, but just for GPU distance matrix calculation. When I just use one GPU, everything goes perfectly; but when it goes to multi-GPU, Error occurs.

Firstly, I got `RuntimeError: CUDA error: initialization error`, and I googled this Error and found a solution: add `mp.set_start_method('spawn')`. But new error occurred, this time the error was `ValueError: bad value(s) in fds_to_keep`, and I've not found a way to solve this error.

Now I'm confused and don't know how to solve it.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.6.8 and pytorch 1.0.0.

For no `mp.set_start_method('spawn')`, the total traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mc/anaconda3/envs/Lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/mc/anaconda3/envs/Lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/mc/nfs/Project/Polaris_Toolkit/src/density.py", line 288, in run_kernel
    d_ts = gpr.pairwise_distance(data_i, data_j, device=device)
  File "/home/mc/nfs/Project/Polaris_Toolkit/src/gpr.py", line 126, in pairwise_distance
    data1, data2 = data1.cuda(device), data2.cuda(device)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: initialization error
```

Here `device` is the index of GPU.

And for `mp.set_start_method('spawn')`, the traceback is:

```
~/nfs/Project/Polaris_Toolkit/src/density.py in multi_gpu_density(trans_matrix, mmd, device, workers, threshold_coe, p, batch_size)
    438             param = (data, indice, threshold, d, d_ma_row, d_ma_col, p)
    439             pr = mp.Process(target=run_kernel, args=param)
--> 440             pr.start()
    441             jobs.append(pr)
    442         for job in jobs:

~/anaconda3/envs/Lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py in start(self)
    103                'daemonic processes are not allowed to have children'
    104         _cleanup()
--> 105         self._popen = self._Popen(self)
    106         self._sentinel = self._popen.sentinel
    107         # Avoid a refcycle if the target function holds an indirect

~/anaconda3/envs/Lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py in _Popen(process_obj)
    221     @staticmethod
    222     def _Popen(process_obj):
--> 223         return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
    224 
    225 class DefaultContext(BaseContext):

~/anaconda3/envs/Lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py in _Popen(process_obj)
    282         def _Popen(process_obj):
    283             from .popen_spawn_posix import Popen
--> 284             return Popen(process_obj)
    285 
    286     class ForkServerProcess(process.BaseProcess):

~/anaconda3/envs/Lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py in __init__(self, process_obj)
     30     def __init__(self, process_obj):
     31         self._fds = []
---> 32         super().__init__(process_obj)
     33 
     34     def duplicate_for_child(self, fd):

~/anaconda3/envs/Lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py in __init__(self, process_obj)
     17         util._flush_std_streams()
     18         self.returncode = None
---> 19         self._launch(process_obj)
     20 
     21     def duplicate_for_child(self, fd):

~/anaconda3/envs/Lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py in _launch(self, process_obj)
     57             self._fds.extend([child_r, child_w])
     58             self.pid = util.spawnv_passfds(spawn.get_executable(),
---> 59                                            cmd, self._fds)
     60             self.sentinel = parent_r
     61             with open(parent_w, 'wb', closefd=False) as f:

~/anaconda3/envs/Lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/util.py in spawnv_passfds(path, args, passfds)
    415             args, [os.fsencode(path)], True, passfds, None, None,
    416             -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, errpipe_read, errpipe_write,
--> 417             False, False, None)
    418     finally:
    419         os.close(errpipe_read)

ValueError: bad value(s) in fds_to_keep
```

I now know that in context `fork`, cuda mustn't be initialized before `multiprocessing`, but I can't understand the error in `spawn`. In fact, I tried to look for `fds_to_keep` keyword in `multiprocessing` and `torch.multiprocessing` source code, but there is no `fds_to_keep` in both the two source codes.

So I'd like to know how to solve this problem, and why `set_start_method('spawn')` doesn't work, what is `fds_to_keep`, where is this keyword.

#### update

I have found `fds_to_keep` error in [`_posixsubprocess.c`](https://github.com/google/python-subprocess32/blob/f74a0843618c62a09701ec9e053df1fe7bf7a099/_posixsubprocess.c#L604), and I looked [`_sanity_check_python_fd_sequence`](https://github.com/google/python-subprocess32/blob/f74a0843618c62a09701ec9e053df1fe7bf7a099/_posixsubprocess.c#L129), I understood `iter_fd` might cause the error. So I went to `multiprocessing/util.py`, in `spawnv_passfds` function, I print variable `passfds` before and after sort.

original code:

```py
# multiprocessing/util.py

def spawnv_passfds(path, args, passfds):
    import _posixsubprocess
    passfds = tuple(sorted(map(int, passfds)))
    errpipe_read, errpipe_write = os.pipe()
    try:
        return _posixsubprocess.fork_exec(
            args, [os.fsencode(path)], True, passfds, None, None,
            -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, errpipe_read, errpipe_write,
            False, False, None)
    finally:
        os.close(errpipe_read)
        os.close(errpipe_write)
```

change:

```py
def spawnv_passfds(path, args, passfds):
    print('before', passfds)
    import _posixsubprocess
    passfds = tuple(sorted(map(int, passfds)))
    print('after', passfds)
    errpipe_read, errpipe_write = os.pipe()
    ...
```

`passfds` didn't change, because it is a tuple which can't be sorted.

Then I changed `passfds = tuple(sorted(map(int, passfds)))` to `passfds = tuple(sorted(map(int, list(passfds))))`, this time the result of `passfds` is:

```
before [77]
after (77,)
before [78, 76, 80, 79]
after (76, 78, 79, 80)
before [78, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 80, 79]
after (75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 78, 79, 80)
```

It is obvious that there are too many 75s in the 3rd `passfds`, so there would appear `iter_fd <= prev_fd`, and error occurs.

So now my question is: why does this phenomenon appear and why there would be nothing wrong when using `fork` (if I don't use any gpu before `multiprocessing`)?